# Mapping a parsed JSON to a POJO

Tags: java, parsing

I'm trying to connect to the Mongo DB using Java without using Spring. Once I get the list of documents from database, I'm using the following code to convert it into my Pojo using the following code,

```
for (Document d : documents) {
            System.out.println(d.toString());
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            JsonParser jsonParser = new JsonParser();
            JsonObject jsonObject = jsonParser.parse(d.toString()).getAsJsonObject();
            JsonReader jsonReader = new JsonReader(new StringReader(jsonObject.toString()));
            jsonReader.setLenient(true);
            Campaign campaign = gson.fromJson(jsonObject, Campaign.class);
        }
```

In my database I have the `Campaign` class as,

```
{
  "_id":"12312312312313212312",
  "USER_NM":"Test User"
}
```

I'm trying to map it to -

```
@Document(
    collection = "LOYALTY_LCT_CAMPAIGNINFO"
)
public class Campaign {
    @Id
    private ObjectId id;
    private String objectId;
    @Field("USER_NM")
    private String userName;
}
```

It isn't mapping it to these fields and the mapping is failing and I'm getting an object with empty fields. Is there any other workaround in this regard?

Comment: Did you create getter() and setters() for the fields in the POJO?

Comment: Yes, I did add them.